# Add SVG with colour overlay using CSS

Tags: html, css, svg

I have a list of icons in SVG format which I am using on a web application.

The icon foreground colour is in black, I would like to use CSS to change this colour to white when hovered over. What is the simplest way to do this using CSS (if possible?)

The HTML markup is as follows:

```
<img class="icon" src="user.svg">
```

CSS

```
.icon {
width: 200px;
height: auto;
}

.icon:hover {
fill: #fff; /* this doesn't work */
}
```

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/bj56tt4u/)

Comment: What you have there is an image, https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/SVG/Element/svg

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```css
.icon {
width: 200px;
height: auto;
}

.icon:hover {
filter: invert(100%);
}

.teste {
background-color: lightblue;
}
```

```html
<div class="teste">
    <img class="icon" src="https://image.flaticon.com/icons/svg/358/358269.svg">
</div>
```

On hover just add

```
.icon:hover {
filter: invert(100%);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Given your current set up, would it be possible for you to do the following instead?:

**HTML**

```
<i class="icon icon-user"></i>
```

**CSS**

```
.icon {
    background-image: url('your/svg/file.svg');
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
}

.icon-user {
    background-position: 50px 100px;
}

.icon-user:hover {
    color: red;
 }
```

So the idea here is that you would use the `background` property of the `<i>` tag to set a background image, being the entire .svg file, then use the `background-position` property to display a specific region within that .svg file. On hover, the color of the `<i>` tag should change to the specified color based on the `color` property.